# Upload video chuck downloaded from one server to another server using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, upload, streaming, afnetworking

I am making an app that will transmit data from glasses to the server for broadcasting.
Til now i am able to download data from glasses to my iPhone document directory.
now i want to upload that downloaded data to my server so that we can broadcast that data to our users.

My iPhone and glasses are connected with each other with the help of WiFi, and i am trying to upload downloaded data via cellular network.

So basically my concept is that download data from glasses and upload that to server.

I have try to make my iPhone as a server to that my back end team could download data from my iPhone.

I got success in this method but the problem is that for this process the client and server should be on same private ip networks.

so now we have left with only one way that we download TS chucks from glasses and same time upload the TS file to our server for broadcasting.

I am using `NFNetworking` to download video chucks from glasses "TS File" but not able to upload that chucks to my server.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.xx.xx.x/abc/trunk/WebServices/app/webroot/xyz"]];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] ; 



operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.aa.a.a/xyz/trunk/WebServices/app/webroot/img/glasses/test/demo.ts"] append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //   NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
        // NSLog(@"download finished!");
        if(_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ZBTM3U8SegmentDownloaderFinishDownload:)])
        {
            [_delegate ZBTM3U8SegmentDownloaderFinishDownload:self];
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];
```

It goes in success state but data is not uploaded on server 
server folder show empty.

```
- (void)postVideoOnServer {


NSDictionary *requestDict = @{ @"uniqueToken":@"101", @"user_id":@"102",};

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:_tsFileName];

NSData *selectedVideo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:@"http://xxx.x.x.xx/myi/public_html/WebServices/broad/axy" parameters:requestDict constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:selectedVideo name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.ts" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];
} success: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                                     {

                                         NSInteger statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;
                                         NSLog(@"Status Code ::%d", statusCode);
                                         NSLog(@"Response ::%@", responseObject);
                                         [self handleVideoServiceResponse:responseObject];
                                     }
                                        failure  : ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Error: %@  %@", operation.responseString, error);

                                     }];
[operation start];
}
```

it always return request time out error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so if you have succesffuly download NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path); then why your questioning Post showing code of download.Shouldn't you post upload method which is creating problem. Also can you play ts formate video?

Comment: are you sure NSData *selectedVideo is not nil? i doubt you mime type too? Just a suggestion try use MIME: video/MP2T

Comment: NSData is not nil , i am getting data from local storage.

Comment: is there is any possible way to upload the downloaded data to another server without saving it to local storage. to make processing more faster.

Comment: are you now able to upload data on server?

Comment: and what about an another architecture, just send necessary command to server A to send video to server B, without even loading data on device side?

Comment: With little bit modification i am able to upload video chunks on server,but the failure rate for uploading chucks are higher than the success. could you suggest some better way to upload video chucks on server.

Comment: for another architecture i mean to say. i connect glasses to code through socket, which connected to my device via wifi network, and trying to upload bytes stream to my server via cellular network.

Comment: Here server A is my Glasses, form where i am getting data in format of m3u8 playlist and processing that playlist to download video stream and upload the binary data to Server B that is my web server for broadcasting.

Comment: i downloading file from server connected through wifi, but want to upload file to my web server using cell network. please reply as soon as possible

Comment: so please update your code in question, which shows chunk uploading

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure NSData *selectedVideo is not nil? i doubt you mime type too? Just a suggestion try use MIME: video/MP2T, it should fix your problem.